# How to plot a double log scale at the x axis?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, logarithmic-scale

I need to plot my Data with a double Log Scale on the x axis. So basically apply `ListLogLinearPlot` two times. Does anyone have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You might first transpose the data such that to put `Log[x]` instead of `x`. Then apply `ListLogLinearPlot`. You will only need to manually take care of the ticks at the x-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the details section of [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) where it says that you can use

`ScalingFunctions -> {{g, InverseFunction[g]}, {f, InverseFunction[f]}}`

[image]

Here I'm, writing the composition `Log[Log[#]]&` as `Log@*Log` for the horizontal axis and `None` for the vertical axis.

```
Plot[
  Log[Log[x]]
  ,{x, 10, 10^7}
  ,ScalingFunctions -> {{Log@*Log, Exp@*Exp}, None}
  ,PlotTheme->"Scientific"
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Luxamba, let me know if this answers your question. Notice that `ScalingFunctions` works on `ListPlot` too.